# Can I append BAT ran in UNC path location

Tags: batch-file, syntax

I have a BAT file that does a basic audit of a AD security group that I have given to a user that needs to be able to have this function.

Can this basic BAT file be ran from a UNC location and set the CSV file to create in what ever folder in the UNC path it was launched from. Because of folder redirection in windows XP the BAT file that is saved in my documents views like a UNC path.

so ever time this is ran it dumps the CSV in c:>windows

example

`date /t >> filname_audit.csv`

`dsget group "CN=security_group_name, OU=more_locations, DC=domain, DC=com" -members | dsget user -display -disabled | find /V "dsget" >> filename_audit.csv`

I might have fat fingered the code, only displayed to give you an idea of what i am doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it within your batch script:

```
pushd \\uncPath
date /t >> filname_audit.csv
dsget group "CN=security_group_name, OU=more_locations, DC=domain, DC=com" -members | dsget user -display -disabled | find /V "dsget" >> filename_audit.csv
popd
```

Or preserve the script as is and setup at run time:

```
pushd \\uncPath
fullPathToScript\yourScript.bat
popd
```

Comment: `pushd "\\uncPath"` <-- use double quotes when the path contains spaces or & etc.